how to get the bar offset of last second occurrence of certain condition in pinescript
Let's say certain conditions on the recent bars are like this.
condition: false false false true(2) false false true(1) false false false
bar offset:  9     8     7     6       5     4      3      2     1     0

How can I get the offset 6 for the last second condition with using ta.xxx methods in pinescript in a concise way?
Suppose the boolean conditions are stored in the variable called AB_crossover.
Consumption: There is no case when adjacent two conditions become true.

I was able to get the solution.
second_bar = bar_index - ta.valuewhen(AB_crossover==true and nz(AB_crossover[1], false)==false, bar_index, 1)

third parameter is key.
0: last condition
1: last second condition

